# Streaming in 256kbps

Tags: naudio

I'm new in NAudio and Audio Programming, and I have questions about streaming in 256kbps, NAudio have some codec to work with this bitrate? I know about MP3 Encode in NAudio don't support. Can I use other codec like ACC in NAudio or another option with this quality to encode?
I'll need to streaming in first side and receive streaming in application on the other side (unicast).
Some ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no reason why any given codec wouldn't support whichever bitrate you want. Have you tried just picking one and setting its bitrate to 256kbps?

Comment: I'm using NAudio code example for Chat, this example list all codecs and bitrate availables, because this I wrote this question @millimoose . I don't see more than 1 types of bitrate available.

Comment: Which example is that? I'm looking at the one from the source code download, `NAudioDemo.NetworkChatDemo`, and that doesn't seem to enumerate all the codec/bitrate combinations supported by the framework. Merely the ones made available to the demo. That said, this example doesn't seem to use MP3, so I might not have the right one.